# Selenium csharp api iedriverserver: unable to find element

Tags: c#, selenium

I am using Selenium C# API with iedriverserver to test an application hosted on local intranet.

I am unable to find element by name (getting Timeout after 20 secs):

```
IWebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
wait.Until((d) => { return d.FindElement(By.Name("UserName")); });
```

The pagesource is showing correct HTML with `name="UserName"` in it.

```
string debug = driver.PageSource.ToString();
```

However, with the same code, I am able to find elements for internet websites (ex - google `FindElement(By.Name("q")`)

Comment: The issue was resolved after setting "Reset all zones to default level" in Internet Options>>Security tab.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was resolved after setting "Reset all zones to default level" in Internet Options>>Security tab.